# JSHint Invalid Regular expression error

Tags: javascript, regex, jshint

I'm using JSHint as Javascript Linter and when executing it I get a "Invalid Regular expression error", the part of the code where I get the error is this:

```
var regexArray = [
    new RegExp(/<(?<tag>iframe)[^>]*src=(\"|\')(?<src>[^\'\" ]*)\2[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/),
    new RegExp(/<(?<tag>(?:div|span))(?=[^>]*(?:class)=(\"|\')[^\'\"]*embed[^\'\"]*\2)(?=[^>]*(?:data-)?(?:src|source|url)=(\"|\')(?<src>[^\'\" ]*)\3)[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/),
    new RegExp(/<(?<tag>div)[^>]*id=\"fb-root\"(?<src>[^\'\" ]*)\2[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/),
    new RegExp(/<(?<tag>div)[^>]*class=\"fb-post\"(?<class>[^\'\" ]*)\2[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1><\/\1>/),
    new RegExp(/<(?<tag>script)>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/),
    new RegExp(/<(?<tag>script)[^>]*src=(\"|\')(?<src>[^\'\" ]*)\2[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/),
    new RegExp(/<(?<tag>div)[^>]*class=(\"|\')(?<class>[pb_feed]*)\2[^>]*>[\s\S]*?<\/\1>/)
]
```

It points the error after the character > in the tag capture group. I already tested these regex in regex testers like regex 101 and they work as expected. I'm not sure what I might be missing. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Note: it’s unnecessary to pass regular expression literals to `new RegExp`. `new RegExp(/a/)` is equivalent to `/a/`.

Comment: Thanks Ry, I did it that way but it still throws the error.

Comment: "The part"? There's a half-dozen long regexes--how about narrowing it down to just the regexes that have problems?

Comment: why are you parsing html that way!?!

Comment: The issue is the named capture groups; support for them is very new in JavaScript. https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-RegExp_named_capture_groups (This table seems a little dated, too; Firefox has disabled them again.)

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm just trying to detect these containers and remove them based on some conditions.

Comment: [Tony the pony he comes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/438992)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @JuanJosePolancoArias Do them one at a time until one blows up.